# Plugin Translation project not found

Tags: plugins, translation

Today I go to our plugin page in WordPress.org and see the translation part under the support forum part.

[image: translation]

However, when I click to translate this plugin, it displays "Not found".

[image: not found]

I joined the translate.wordpress.org page, but I cannot find my project. How can I add my plugin into WordPress translation. We used to use Transifex project for our user to contribute their translate, we would prefer use WordPress translate cos it will be more easier for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating WordPress plugins is an experimental project. Not all plugins listed in the repo are available yet. Quoting the [translating WordPress](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/) page,

> The project currently contains only a couple of experimental plugins
>   for translation.